# How to check if the url is working using a RxJava?

Tags: android, rx-java

I have json response ["url1","url2","url3"..."url10"]
Each url contains addres of image.
I got list of these urls using this method:

```
@GET("task-m-001/list.php")
fun getItems(): Single<List<String>>
```

2 of 10 urls doesn't works. I need to check each url and filter brokens.

my method:

```
    fun getItems(){
    _networkState.postValue(NetworkState.LOADING)

    try {
        compositeDisposable.add(
            apiService.getItems()
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .flatMapObservable { items ->
                    Observable.fromIterable(items)
                        .flatMap{
                          //Here i need to check urls... How to do that?
                        }
                }
                .toList()
                .subscribe({ urlList ->
                    Log.i(TAG, "getItems: $urlList")
                    val itemsResponse = itemsResponseConverter.getItemResponse(urlList)
                    _downloadedItemsResponse.postValue(itemsResponse)
                    _networkState.postValue(NetworkState.LOADED)
                },
                    {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Error - $it")
                        _networkState.postValue(NetworkState.ERROR)
                    })
        )
    }catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.message.toString())
    }
}
```

How to do that using rxJava?

Comment: Have you looked into the RxJava map methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all try to request to the image url with URL and HttpURLConnection and get the response code.
if image is valid, the response code will be 200 otherwise is not valid

This is your code now:

```
fun getItems(){
    _networkState.postValue(NetworkState.LOADING)

    try {
        compositeDisposable.add(
            apiService.getItems()
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .flatMapObservable { items ->
                    Observable.fromIterable(items)
                        .flatMap{
                          val url:URL = URL(imageUrl)
                          val http: HttpURLConnection: = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                          val statusCode: Integer = http.responseCode
                          return if(statusCode == 200) // correct image url
                        }
                }
                .toList()
                .subscribe({ urlList ->
                    Log.i(TAG, "getItems: $urlList")
                    val itemsResponse = itemsResponseConverter.getItemResponse(urlList)
                    _downloadedItemsResponse.postValue(itemsResponse)
                    _networkState.postValue(NetworkState.LOADED)
                },
                    {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Error - $it")
                        _networkState.postValue(NetworkState.ERROR)
                    })
        )
    }catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.message.toString())
    }
}
```

Comment: Error has occured. ImageItemsDataSource: Error - java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused